# Javascript checking radiobuttons

Tags: php, javascript

I got this code

```
    <?php foreach($this->question as $question): ?>
<div class="question">
    <?php echo $question['question'] ?>          </div>


<?php if($this->activeEdition["id"]!=20) { ?>

<div class="answers">
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($question['answers'] as $answer):
    ?>
    <input type="radio" name="question[<?php echo $question['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $answer['id'] ?>" id="<?php echo
           $answer['id']
    ?>" class="radio_answer radio_answer_<?php echo $i; ?>" >
    <label for="<?php echo $answer['id'] ?>"><?php echo $answer['answer'] ?></label>
    <?php
    if(count($question['answers']) > 3){
    echo '<br/>';
    }
    ?>
<?php
$i++;
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

How to check in easy and simplest way in javascript if in every question is checked one radio button?

Answer (score 0):

If all answers are required, than you should set the first radio to selected in every answer when you generate it. That's the easiest way.

Of course you can check it with JS, but it will be ugly. Here is a demo code:

```
<script>
    function check(){
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var names = [];
        var checked = 0;

        for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
            if(inputs[i].type=='radio'){
                inArray = false;
                for(var j=0;j<names.length;j++){
                    if(names[j]==inputs[i].name){
                        inArray = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!inArray){
                    names.push(inputs[i].name);
                }
                if(inputs[i].checked){
                    checked++;
                }
            }
        }

        return names.length==checked;
    }
</script>
<input type="radio" name="a">
<input type="radio" name="a"><br/>
<input type="radio" name="b">
<input type="radio" name="b"><br/>
<input type="radio" name="b">
<input type="radio" name="c">
<input type="radio" name="c"><br/>
<input type="radio" name="d">
<input type="radio" name="d">
<input type="radio" name="d">
<input type="button" onClick="alert(check());">
```

If you know the number of questions you can simplify it and maybe there is some better solution to check in_array.

With jQuery its nicer.

Answer (score 0):

ok I done better solution using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkform()
{
    var ilosc = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
    var n = $("input:checked").length;
    if (n != ilosc.length)
    {
    alert('Proszę zaznaczyć wszyskie odpowiedzi');

    return false;
    }else return true;

}
</script>
```